# Get index value in python list comprehension (for in preceded with variable)

Tags: python, list, for-loop

This syntax is able to define new list above list (or array):

```
[v for v in ['a', 'b']]
```

But how to get the index of the list? This doesn't work

```
[k for k, v in ['a', 'b']]
```

Expected output

```
[0, 1]
```

Comment: There are no keys in a list.

Comment: What do you mean by key of a list?

Comment: so its not possible with this syntactic sugar?

Comment: @MitchellOlislagers key = order of the value in the list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you have meant indexes, as there are no keys in list. We can get them like this:

```
indexes = [index for index,element in enumerate(your_list)]
```

But this isn't really necessary, we can get length of the list and get indexes from it as indexes are from 0 to [length of list]-1:

```
length = len(your_list)
indexes = list(range(length))
```

Comment: Sidenote, [`l` is a bad variable name since it looks like `1` and `I`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid). I would use `n` instead, personally.

Answer (score 3):

```
[idx for idx, val in enumerate(['a', 'b'])]
```

output

```
[0, 1]
```

Comment: Please do not use `k, v`. There are no keys and values in a list, OP is already confused about it. Maybe use `index, element` instead.

Comment: it's just index as there is no key in the list object

Comment: I assume luky who asked the question is from another programming language field

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range):

```py
range(len(['a', 'b']))
```

`range()` will return a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence). If you need a list specifically, you can do

```py
list(range(len(['a', 'b'])))
```

As mentioned in the comments, in python lists do not have keys.

Comment: [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) isn't a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) or even an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator). It's actually a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence).

Answer (score 1):

```py
enumerated_list = [(index, value) for index, value in enumerate(['a', 'b'])]
print(enumerated_list)
```

output:
`[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b')]`

Comment: No need to unpack `enumerate` just to pack it again. Just do `list(enumerate(['a', 'b']))`

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant `index`. Remember that lists have no keys, those are dictionaries.

```py
[index for index, value in enumerate(['a', 'b'])]
```

The `enumerate` function is basically `range` but it returns the index and the value.

Read more on `enumerate` [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/enumerate).